# MacOS app - why does CommandLine.arguments of an already open app not contain the passed --args arguments?

Tags: macos, cocoa, appdelegate, macos-catalina

I have a macOS app which most users use by drag and dropping images on the app icon or my menu bar icon. Some users also use my app through Terminal by running the following commands:

```
open -a /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-bomyuotvsgqtachwwiidvpiaktgc/Build/Products/Debug/AppName.app /Users/username/Downloads/image.jpeg
```

My app handles the link/links being passed in the `func application(_ sender: NSApplication, openFiles filenames: [String])` method of AppDelegate.

This works fine so far. If my app is already open, the `openFiles` still gets called by MacOS with the new image path and my app opens a new window to display it. This all works well.

Now I want users to be able to pass certain arguments to my app. For example this:

```
open -a /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-bomyuotvsgqtachwwiidvpiaktgc/Build/Products/Debug/AppName.app /Users/username/Downloads/image.jpeg --args full
```

Here I want to receive the `full` argument. I read on few other posts to use the `CommandLine.arguments` API. But this doesn't seem to contain the arguments. Each time the value of `CommandLine.arguments` equals to this:

```
["/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-bomyuotvsgqtachwwiidvpiaktgc/Build/Products/Debug/AppName.app/Contents/MacOS/AppName", "-NSDocumentRevisionsDebugMode", "YES"]
```

I think this is because the `CommandLine.arguments` only works when the app is initially launched and arguments are passed into the `main` function. But for an already opened app, these don't get passed as `main` isn't called again for an already running app.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the -n option of the `open` command, you would always get a new instance of the app that could receive the arguments this way. However, you probably don`t want to have multiple instances of your app.

This means that you need a small command line program that performs a request with the arguments if the app is already running. In case the app is not running yet, it should probably start the app with the arguments.

There are several ways to communicate between a command line program and a GUI app. Depending on the exact requirements, they have corresponding advantages and disadvantages.

**Command Line Tool**

However, the actual process is always the same. Here exemplary with the help of the DistributedNotificationCenter, there the command line tool could look like this:

```
import AppKit


func stdError(_ msg: String) {
    guard let msgData = msg.data(using: .utf8) else { return }
    FileHandle.standardError.write(msgData)
}


private func sendRequest(with args: [String]) {
    if let json = try? JSONEncoder().encode(args) {
        
        DistributedNotificationCenter.default().postNotificationName(Notification.Name(rawValue: "\(bundleIdent).openRequest"),
                                                                     object: String(data: json, encoding: .utf8),
                                                                     userInfo: nil,
                                                                     deliverImmediately: true)
    }
}

let bundleIdent = "com.software7.test.NotificationReceiver"
let runningApps = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications
let isRunning = !runningApps.filter { $0.bundleIdentifier == bundleIdent }.isEmpty
let args = Array(CommandLine.arguments.dropFirst())

if(!isRunning) {
    if let url = NSWorkspace.shared.urlForApplication(withBundleIdentifier: bundleIdent) {
        let configuration = NSWorkspace.OpenConfiguration()
        configuration.arguments = args
        NSWorkspace.shared.openApplication(at: url,
                                           configuration: configuration,
                                           completionHandler: { (app, error) in
                                            if app == nil {
                                                stdError("starting \(bundleIdent) failed with error: \(String(describing: error))")
                                            }
                                            exit(0)
                                           })
    } else {
        stdError("app with bundle id \(bundleIdent) not found")
    }
} else {
    sendRequest(with: args)
    exit(0)
}


dispatchMain()
```

Note: since DistributedNotificationCenter can no longer send the userInfo with current macOS versions, the arguments are simply converted to JSON and passed with the object parameter.

**App**

The actual application can then use applicationDidFinishLaunching to determine if it was started freshly with arguments. If so, the arguments are evaluated. It also registers an observer for the notification. When a notification is received, the JSON is converted to the arguments. Here they are simply displayed in an alert in both cases. Could look like this:

```
import Cocoa

@main
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    
    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let bundleIdent = "com.software7.test.NotificationReceiver"
        DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(self,
                                                            selector: #selector(requestReceived(_:)),
                                                            name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "\(bundleIdent).openRequest"),
                                                            object: nil)
        let args = Array(CommandLine.arguments.dropFirst())
        if !args.isEmpty {
            processArgs(args)
        }
    }
    
    private func processArgs(_ args: [String]) {
        let arguments = args.joined(separator: "\n")
        InfoDialog.show("request with arguments:", arguments)
    }
    
    @objc private func requestReceived(_ request: Notification) {
        if let jsonStr = request.object as? String {
            if let json = jsonStr.data(using: .utf8) {
                if let args = try? JSONDecoder().decode([String].self, from: json) {
                    processArgs(args)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


struct InfoDialog {
    
    static func show(_ title: String, _ info: String) {
        let alert = NSAlert()
        alert.messageText = title
        alert.informativeText = info
        alert.alertStyle = .informational
        alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
        alert.runModal()
    }
        
}
```

As mentioned earlier, the appropriate method of inter-process communication should be chosen depending on the exact requirements, but the flow would always be roughly the same.

**Test**

[image: Test Call]

Comment: Thanks, this was perfect and got me going. I do think Apple should make this easier instead of having to make a separate helper app.

Comment: This solution does work for non-sandboxed apps. My app is a sandboxed app for the MacOS App Store and gives the following error when trying to access the file at the passed argument: `Sandbox extension data required immediately for flavor public.file-url, but failed to obtain. Sandbox extension creation failed: client lacks entitlements? for path: /path/to/file`. Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried to use the `userInfo` dict which includes the `URL` instead of the `object` as `object` only allows String. However I ran into another limitation that `userInfo` is not supported for sandboxed apps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61963965/distributednotificationcenter-how-to-pass-data-between-applications

Comment: I see. Sandbox. Anyway, in the example I encoded the arguments as JSON string and sent it via `object` parameter. In the receiving program you can construct an URLs out of it. However when trying to access it it would give something like `couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission...`. One has to use the available mechanisms to get access rights to a specific file at a specific path from a sandboxed app, e.g. by using an NSOpenPanel. Tricky.

Comment: Yea. The solution works if I disable sandbox but Apple won’t allow that in the App Store unfortunately :( I tried to use ‘bookmark’ by getting the bookmark security scoped URL, then converting the bookmark data to base64 and sending that string into the main app using your mechanism. But for some reason I am having problems deciding the base64 back to the bookmark URL. Will try later and get back to you if I figure it out.